# php variable defined yet undefined

Tags: php, cakephp

In my cakephp (1.3) app's controller I set a couple of array variables, when in the view I print them to the error log, they are defined and display their values. In addition when I log $this->viewVars - I see all the relevant variables and nothing is amiss. However when I attempt to pass these variable as options to the form input,

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ages', array('options' => $ages)); ?>
```

it complains that the variable $ages is undefined - as with the other array variables.

Can anyone give insight into what might be happening here? I don't understand how I can log the variables on one line and yet on the next they are treated as undefined? (Note PHP version is 5.3.20 - the app is old) Is this an issue with namespacing, scoping etc?

Comment: when you print $ages, does it print in in array format?

Comment: You said $viewVars shows an array. So is 'ages' an array key rather than a variable?

Comment: @bablu yes it prints it in array format.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea It shows [ages] => Array ( [1] => male [2] => female )

Comment: Right, so it is an array. So you need to access it like an array.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea I do that, I can log the array, but the error on the page says undefined index 'ages'. I am utterly stumped.

Comment: @user1658296 When you receive errors, please always post the _exact_, _complete_ error, ie message, line number, context, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your code:

**From:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('ages', array('options' => $ages)); ?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php
$opts=array('ages' => $ages);
echo $this->Form->input($opts); 
?>
```

**And you can access ages via:**

```
$opts['ages'];
```